# How to make a browser display a "save as dialog" so the user can save the content of a string to a file on his system?

Tags: javascript, save, savefiledialog

How can I make a browser display a "save as dialog" so the user can save the content of a string to a file on his system?

For example:

```
var myString = "my string with some stuff";
save_to_filesystem(myString,"myString.txt");
```

Resulting in something like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: You'll find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Comment: @ArnarYngvason is this the same process as doing this in angularjs?

Comment: @bleykFaust, the procedure is the same across all frontend js applications.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

EDIT 2022: Please see other answers regarding File System API

---

In case anyone is still wondering...

I did it like this:

```html
<a href="data:application/xml;charset=utf-8,your code here" download="filename.html">Save</a>
```

can't remember my source but it uses the following techniques\features:

1. html5 download attribute
2. data URI's

Found the reference:

http://paxcel.net/blog/savedownload-file-using-html5-javascript-the-download-attribute-2/

---

EDIT:
As you can gather from the comments, this does **NOT** work in

1. Internet Explorer (however works in Edge v13 and later)
2. Opera Mini

http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: As of Jan 2019, it works in (non iOS) Safari, Android Browser. Still no iOS Safari, Opera Mini, or IE     https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: @SeanKPS Can you force it to **prompt the user** for the folder in which to save it, despite browser settings?

Comment: Well, its modern, short, and it works. But, **it gives no "save as..." dialog** anymore. I wish user be able to change file name before save.

Comment: In win7 chrome 79, **relies on browser setting**. If user unchecked 'Ask where to save each file before downloading', it will download directly.

Comment: Best method now (May 2021) seems to be the File system access API detailed here: https://web.dev/file-system-access/

Comment: File system access looks pretty cool, but from what I can tell it has very spotty support: https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api

Answer (score 28):

There is a new spec called the [Native File System API](https://wicg.github.io/native-file-system/) that allows you to do this properly like [this](https://wicg.github.io/native-file-system/#api-choosefilesystementries):

```
const result = await window.chooseFileSystemEntries({ type: "save-file" });
```

There is a demo [here](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/text-editor/), but I believe it is using an origin trial so it may not work in your own website unless you sign up or enable a config flag, and it obviously [only works in Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#search=native%20file). If you're making an Electron app this might be an option though.

Comment: Tackling this in May 2021, this seemed to be the easiest method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker. Note the API has changed since the original post. See this helpful article as well: https://web.dev/file-system-access/

Comment: This doesn't work in most browsers yet.

Comment: The feature is no longer supported. Mozilla itself excluded Firefox from the list of the feature supporting browsers. So I recommend to downvote this answer.

Comment: It was never supported by Firefox. I said it was chrome only in the answer.

Answer (score 18):

There is a javascript library for this, see [FileSaver.js on Github](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

However the `saveAs()` function won't send pure string to the browser, you need to convert it to `blob`:

```
function data2blob(data, isBase64) {
  var chars = "";

  if (isBase64)
    chars = atob(data);
  else
    chars = data;

  var bytes = new Array(chars.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = chars.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(bytes)]);
  return blob;
}
```

and then call `saveAs` on the blob, as like:

```
var myString = "my string with some stuff";
saveAs( data2blob(myString), "myString.txt" );
```

Of course remember to include the above-mentioned javascript library on your webpage using `<script src=FileSaver.js>`

Comment: This just saves "myString.txt" to my Downloads folder, without showing a dialog box.

Comment: Ahh, no I don't! They all save automatically. So is this always a per-browser feature, or is there a way to trigger the behavior with a script?

Comment: I believe it is a per-browser feature. In chrome, you set it in settings, advanced settings, checkbox "Ask where to save each file before downloading"

Comment: It is not possible to get a Win32 SaveAs dialog under normal circumstances. Best method is to use filename from a user input.

Answer (score 10):

This is possible using this cross browser javascript implementation of the HTML5 `saveAs` function: https://github.com/koffsyrup/FileSaver.js

If all you want to do is save text then the above script works in all browsers(including all versions of IE), using nothing but JS.

Answer (score 7):

Using [`showSaveFilePicker()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker):

```js
const handle = await showSaveFilePicker({
    suggestedName: 'name.txt',
    types: [{
        description: 'Text file',
        accept: {'text/plain': ['.txt']},
    }],
});

const blob = new Blob(['Some text']);

const writableStream = await handle.createWritable();
await writableStream.write(blob);
await writableStream.close();
```

Comment: Not currently supported in Firefox/Safari.

Comment: For TypeScript, you need to doo the following changes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71309058/property-showsavefilepicker-does-not-exist-on-type-window-typeof-globalthis

Answer (score 5):

Solution using only javascript

```
function saveFile(fileName,urlFile){
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.style = "display: none";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = urlFile;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove();
}

let textData = `El contenido del archivo
que sera descargado`;
let blobData = new Blob([textData], {type: "text/plain"});
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
//let url = "pathExample/localFile.png"; // LocalFileDownload
saveFile('archivo.txt',url);
```

Comment: this doesn't work as specified: it saves the file but not through a dialogue

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@ronald-coarite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2154661/ronald-coarite) answer, here is my solution:

```
function saveTxtToFile(fileName: string, textData: string) {
  const blobData = new Blob([textData], { type: 'text/plain' });
  const urlToBlob = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);

  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.href = urlToBlob;
  a.download = fileName;
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(urlToBlob);
  a.remove();
}

saveTxtToFile('myFile.json', JSON.stringify(myJson));
```

Comment: This won't show any dialog.

Comment: Sorry to hear, Serg. For us it's working fine in production and with any modern browser.

Comment: Does it actually show "Save as.." dialog or just start downloading?

Comment: @Serg: This seems to be a browser specific setting. There's a checkbox in FF settings: "Always ask you where to save files". I'm not aware of being able to make the box appear otherwise.