# Convert HTML Table to Json file

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, converters

Is it possible to convert a HTML table to json like this:

Name Gender Age

John M 18

Mike M 19

Json:

```
     {"Values" : {

    "1" : {
                "name": "John",
                "Gender": "M",
                "Age": "18"
            },

    "2": {
                "name": "Mike",
                "Gender": "M",
                "Age": "19"
            },
}}
```

I already have this code:

```
    (function() {
    var jsonArr = [];
    var obj = {};
    var thNum = document.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
    var arrLength = document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;

    for(i = 0; i<arrLength;i++){
        if(i%thNum==0){
            obj = {};
        }
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[i%thNum].innerHTML;
        var content = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML;
        obj[head] = content;
        if(i%thNum==0){
            jsonArr.push(obj);
        }   
    }           
    document.write("<br>"+JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
})();
```

The script convert this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<TABLE border="3" rules="all" bgcolor="#E7E7E7" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<TR>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Date</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><B>Teacher</B></font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">?</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Hour</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Subject</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Class</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Room</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">(Teacher)</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">(Room)</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">XYY</font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><B>Information</B></font></TH>
<TH align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">(Le.) nach</font></TH>
</TR>
<TR><TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">24.9.</font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><B><strike>Dohe</strike></B></font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Free</font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">1</font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><strike>Math</strike></font> </TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">(9)</font> </TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">---</font> </TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial"><strike>Dohe</strike></font></TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">A001</font></TD>
<TD align=center>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD align=center>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD align=center><font size="3" face="Arial">Free.</font></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<script>
(function() {
    var jsonArr = [];
    var obj = {};
    var thNum = document.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
    var arrLength = document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;

    for(i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            obj = {};
        }
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[i%thNum].innerHTML;
        var content = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML;
        obj[head] = content;
        if(i%thNum === 0){
            jsonArr.push(obj);
        }   
    }           
    document.write("<br>"+JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

to this:

```
[{"Date":"24.9.","Teacher":"Dohe","?":"Free","Hour":"1","Subject":"Math ","Class":"(9) ","Room":"--- ","(Teacher)":"Dohe","(Room)":"A001","XYY":" ","Information":" ","(Le.) nach":"Free."}]
```

But I need the "Values" tag before and the "1", "2", wich should be created automatically by row. 
And at least ist it possible to write this into a new .json file like data.json?

Comment: provide a sample table as input and sample output of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to represent the array of rows as an object, change `jsonArr.push(obj)` to `jsonObj[++rowIx] = obj`, where `jsonObj` has previously been initialized to `{}`, and `rowIx` is a counter that has been initialized to 0 (probably simpler than doing math on `i`).

The expected output you posted is not valid JSON, so I'm assuming that it's supposed to be wrapped by another set of braces:

```
document.write("<br>"+JSON.stringify({"Values": jsonObj}));
```

As for saving to a file, this is tricky to do in a portable manner.  There are several other answers that address this, including the following:

- [Javascript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)
- [How to make a browser display a "save as dialog" so the user can save the content of a string to a file on his system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336663/how-to-make-a-browser-display-a-save-as-dialog-so-the-user-can-save-the-conten)

Comment: `<script>
(function() {
 var jsonArr = [];
 var obj = {};
 var jsonObj = {};
 var thNum = document.getElementsByTagName('th').length;
 var arrLength = document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;
 
 for(i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
  if(i%thNum === 0){
   obj = {};
  }
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('th')[i%thNum].innerHTML;
  var content = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML;
  obj[head] = content;
  if(i%thNum === 0){
   jsonObj[rowIx] = obj;
  }  
 }           
 document.write("<br>"+JSON.stringify({"Values": jsonObj}));
})();
</script>` like this ? It dosn´t work ...

Comment: You aren't initializing or incrementing the counter (`rowIx`).

Comment: now I added `var rowIx = {};` but now it just show me one row and [object Object] instead 1 or so. It also shows the last row and not the first.

Comment: `rowIx` is a counter, a number that counts 1, 2, ...; I'll update the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Thank you ! Now it works exactly how i need it. One last question: can I save this json into a file on the server e.g. data.json? without any work from the user, that views the site ?

Comment: If you want to download without user interaction, you might look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer.  If that doesn't work for you, I suggest that you post a new question with the specific behavior you're looking for.