# Save Base64 to File as Image

Tags: javascript, base64

I am trying to save a base64 to string as Image. I used the Javascript Code below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Download base64 Image</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function DownloadImageAndSave(){

var base64string = "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";

var img = new Blob([base64string],{type: 'image/png'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(img);
url.download = 'signature.png';
}
</script>
<form name="testJsImage" id="testJsImage" />
<input type="button" name="buttonDownload" value="DownLoad Image" onclick="DownloadImageAndSave();" />
</form>
</head>
</html>
```

It should convert to base 64 and download, But instead i get this error From the Javascript console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.
    at DownloadImageAndSave (JsDownloadTest.htm:9)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (JsDownloadTest.htm:15)
```

Do i appear to be missing something?

**Edit**

I have put the byte in arrays and even worse, the base64 image wont download.

Comment: Can you please try to remove /9j/ which looks like a virtual file path and not part of base 64 string..

Comment: @bestinamir, if i do that it wont return anything

Comment: That wasn’t right, but here’s a different solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/42385950/10634638

Comment: @bestinamir its supposed to get the array, and download the file.

Comment: I see, here’s another one https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473992/10634638

Comment: @bestinamir , yes this works ... but if i want to copy to a directory what must I do

Comment: Oh, then this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29650941/10634638