# How to show save as dialog box in Angular without changing browser settings

Tags: angular, browser, download, save-as

**Platform used**

Front end : Angular

Backend : WebAPI

**Requirement** : Need to show the **Save as dialog**, once file is returned from the Server (API - ActionResult) to Angular (front end)

**Explanation:**
Front end: Sending the data through FormData submit (action link)
Back End: Returned the File from Action Result

[Save as Dilaog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rNOd.png)

(Instead of changing the browser settings, need to handle it in code)

[Browser settings permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu0Lr.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a browser display a "save as dialog" so the user can save the content of a string to a file on his system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336663/how-to-make-a-browser-display-a-save-as-dialog-so-the-user-can-save-the-conten)

Comment: @PatricioVargas Saving the file is not problem. Have to show the "Save as Dialog" before download. I have tried the solution marked in that post. It doesn't show the "Save as dialog" before downloading it (doesn't override the browser settings) code: var pom = document.createElement('a');
pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent('Hello world!'));
pom.setAttribute('download', 'test.txt');
if (document.createEvent) { var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); event.initEvent('click', true, true);
pom.dispatchEvent(event); }
else { pom.click(); }

Answer (score 0):

1) We can't change browser settings from javascript but still, you can prompt the dialog box with download attribute, check the below link

http://paxcel.net/blog/savedownload-file-using-html5-javascript-the-download-attribute-2/

this can be triggered from front end only, to automatically prompt the dialog box you have to make javascript button click  from your controller

Comment: When the browser settings is in default state, the prompt doesn't get show even on download attribute **Code:** var pom = document.createElement('a'); pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent('Hello world!')); **pom.setAttribute('download', 'test.txt');** if (document.createEvent) { var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); event.initEvent('click', true, true); pom.dispatchEvent(event); } else { pom.click(); }. Here i have added the download attribute in <a> tag, still the file download automatically (didn't show prompt box)

Comment: Seems like this is not possible