# Creating a directory picker to download a file to clients computer using js

Tags: javascript, html, save, filesaver.js

I have written an application where on button click a *.docx* file is generated on the server and returned to client as base64 string. What I want to do now, is to let the user download the file in a directory of their choice.

To demonstrate what I mean, if I instead want to upload a file having a `<input type='file'/>` opens a dialog such like this [image]

Where I can select the file. Is there any way to open this kind of dialog for a download button?  I understand that the web-page doesn't receive the actual path on a clients pc for security reasons, but if you can chose an upload file, there is no reason to not chose a download path right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a browser display a "save as dialog" so the user can save the content of a string to a file on his system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336663/how-to-make-a-browser-display-a-save-as-dialog-so-the-user-can-save-the-conten)

Answer (score 0):

No, for security reasons this is not possible.

See:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/42