# Property 'showSaveFilePicker' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, window, eslint, typescript-typings

```
const opts = {
      suggestedName: 'data',
      types: [
        {
          description: 'NewCSV',
          accept: { 'text/csv': ['.csv'] },
        },
      ],
    };
    const handle = await (window).showSaveFilePicker(opts);
```

now I have the type error **Property 'showSaveFilePicker' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'**, providing type as **any** solves the issue of type error.

```
const handle = await (<any>window).showSaveFilePicker(opts);
```

But still it will show the eslint error **Unsafe call of an `any` typed value**. So the only solution I know is to disable eslint for the file. Is there any other way to avoid both the type error and eslint error ?

Answer (score 37):

It seems like TypeScript's type definitions for the file system access API are currently broken: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141908

For now, try installing the package `@types/wicg-file-system-access` to fix the types:

```bash
# Yarn
yarn add --dev @types/wicg-file-system-access

# NPM
npm install --save-dev @types/wicg-file-system-access
```

You will also need to update the types field of the tsconfig.json with:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [ "@types/wicg-file-system-access"]
   }
```

Comment: I use Angular, not ReactJS. In my case this does not help, I'm still getting "Property 'showDirectoryPicker' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'" error

Comment: This solution worked for me on Angular

Comment: @Alexander Just realized, it worked for me in Angular, but by adding the type to compilerOptions in `tsconfig.app.json`, not `tsconfig.json`

Comment: This solution worked for me in a Svelte project, as well.

Answer (score 0):

had to `npm i @types/wicg-file-system-access` in my Angular project home directory.